# How to find the determinant of system of PDE given below. Also explain the character of the system.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

Consider a two dimensional fow with Cartesian velocity components u and v. Assume that flow is steady, inviscid, incompressible and irrotational. The governing equations are then mass
conservation, equation (1), and the irrotational condition, equation (2),
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 0 \hspace{0.5cm} \cdots (1)$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 0 \hspace{0.5cm} \cdots (2)$$

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Please be more precise with your question and tell us your work so far.

Answer (score 0):

HINT :
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x\partial y} = 0 \hspace{0.5cm} $$
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} - \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x\partial y} = 0 \hspace{0.5cm} $$
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}=0$$
$$u(x,y)=f(x+iy)+g(x-iy)$$
$f$ and $g$ are arbitrary functions to be determined according to bondary conditions.

Then integrate  $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ with respect to $x$  in order to find $v(x,y)$.

Comment: I think you got the wrong sign and your approach yields an elliptic equation.

Comment: OK. Fixed. Thanks for the remark.